# Ember defining model in route causing error

Tags: django, ember.js, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Ember, and I'm trying to set up a template that displays information about an external model (product). So I have an admin route:

```
App.AdminRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var admin_brand = this.store.find('brand', 1);
        return this.store.find('product', {brand: admin_brand});
    }
});
```

controller:

```
App.AdminController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});
```

and template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="admin">
    <div class="row">
        {{#each}}
            {{name}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

But I'm getting a JS error:

```
Error while processing route: admin undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm also using ember-data-django-rest-adapter for my actual data (which seems to be working fine otherwise). If I pass it a static array of objects in the route it works fine. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Also, is this even the correct way to go about this? Finally, is there a better way to debug these types of issues? I have the Chrome extension but it doesn't seem to help with these extremely generic errors, so any other tips on that would be awesome. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ember data...

The issue is that the call to `this.store.find('brand', 1)` returns a promise, not a value. In order to use the value in the call to `this.store.find('product', {brand: admin_brand})` you would need to use `.then()` to access the resolved value.

Something like this should work.

```
App.AdminRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var self = this;
        return self.store.find('brand', 1).then(function(admin_brand){
            return self.store.find('product', {brand: admin_brand})
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it definitely makes more sense this way, but unfortunately I'm still running into an error (a new one anyway). `Error while processing route: admin Cannot read property 'find' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` on the find('product'). Do I need to do anything specific in the controller or the template in this case? After some more digging I think there may be some other issue causing problems (looking at the ember debugger, my product objects don't always exist, but after visiting product/1 they do get added in the debugger)

Comment: that issue is a scope issue. I fixed the code in the answer to use `self` instead of `this`. Try it with the code above and see if it works.

Comment: Ah yes that also makes sense, unfortunately I'm getting a new error: `Error while processing route: admin Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at encodeURIComponent (native)`

Comment: hmm... any chance of being able to reproduce the error using http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: I'm trying to get one going, but I'm not sure about the best way to create some dummy model instances to play with. Here's the bin if it helps at all: [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lijopumakiza/1/edit)

Comment: which adapter are you using in your app? are you using the FixtureAdapter or RESTAdapter?

Comment: I'm using the DjangoRESTAdapter, I just figured the fixtureadapter would be the easiest way to test it on jsbin (I can switch it up if there's a better way to populate that test data)